# spring-data mongodb exclude fields from update

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How to make sure that specific fields can be inserted upon creation, but can optionally be excluded when updating the object.
I'm essentially looking for something like the following:

```
mongoOperations.save(theObject, <fields to ignore>)
```

From what I see, recently introduced **@ReadOnlyProperty** will ignore the property both for inserts and updates.

I was able to get the desired behavior by implementing my Custom MongoTemplate and overriding its **doUpdate** method as follows:

```
@Override
protected WriteResult doUpdate(String collectionName, Query query,
        Update originalUpdate, Class<?> entityClass, boolean upsert, boolean multi) {

    Update updateViaSet = new Update();

    DBObject dbObject = originalUpdate.getUpdateObject();
    Update filteredUpdate = Update.fromDBObject(dbObject, "<fields to ignore>");

    for(String key : filteredUpdate.getUpdateObject().keySet()){

        Object val = filteredUpdate.getUpdateObject().get(key);

        System.out.println(key + "::" + val);

        updateViaSet.set(key, filteredUpdate.getUpdateObject().get(key));
    }

    return super
            .doUpdate(collectionName, query, updateViaSet, entityClass, upsert, multi);
}
```

But the issue is that now it will use [Mongo $set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) form of updates for everything, not just for specific cases.
Please advise if there is any simpler (and correct) way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

While creating an update object, use $setOnInsert instead of $set. It is available in spring mongo as well.

> If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a document, then $setOnInsert assigns the specified values to the fields in the document. If the update operation does not result in an insert, $setOnInsert does nothing.